# How to apply server side hooks in TFS - Git repositories

Tags: git, tfs, githooks

I am working on SVN to git migration project.

I would like to apply server side hooks(like check in commits and other basic checks on code) in TFS-Git repositories. I couldn't find any documentation online.

Has anyone worked on this area. could you please share your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. TFS/VSTS Git repos currently do not support Git hooks.

Comment: Then how could we implement pre-commit hooks?

Comment: VS2017 added pre-commit hook support. https://andrewlock.net/git-integration-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: Hi Daniel, we have upgraded TFS server to 2017. Still finding way to implement server side hooks.

Comment: @RajkumarThambu My answer is still accurate: Server hooks are not supported. Visual Studio (**not** TFS) 2017 added support for hooks, but they are client hooks, not server hooks.

Comment: The alternative is to use the Service Hooks and for example use an Web Hook that post the a Web server. Then you implement your hook on the server. Not exactly the same but it works too.