# Can I use service hooks to reject pushes to an Azure DevOps reopsitory?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Apparently, [server-side git hooks are not supported on Azure Devops repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296831/how-to-apply-server-side-hooks-in-tfs-git-repositories).

Is there any way to use external services to reject/approve pushes into my repository according to my own custom criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with external services via [service hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops).

Pull requests have an option for [approval from external services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-approval-from-external-services).

Comment: I know that you can approve or deny pull requests with external services.  Is it possible to approve or deny commits at the time when they're pushed to the repository?

Comment: @PortMan branch policies can help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops

Comment: No, I want to be able to approve/reject commits according to my own custom criteria, and not just the criteria that Microsoft has implemented in their branch policies.

Comment: You can add build validation and in the build put your logic.

Comment: 3 years later, same need here. @PortMan do you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I never did.

Comment: Another 1 1/2 years and a world wide pandemic later, same need here. @PortMan do you ever found a solution?

Comment: Nope.  Never did.